# Parsing CSS transform for rotate3d values using regex

Tags: javascript, css, regex, css-transforms

I need to separate css transform values into an array, but keeping rotate values together.

For example:

```
'translate3d(20px, 5px, 10px) rotateX(20deg) rotateY(10deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew3d(20deg, 10deg) rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(100deg) rotateZ(-30deg)'
```

needs to be

```
[
    'translate3d(20px, 5px, 10px)',
    'rotateX(20deg) rotateY(10deg) rotateZ(0deg)',
    'skew3d(20deg, 10deg)',
    'rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(100deg) rotateZ(-30deg)'
]
```

you can assume that the rotates will always be in this order `rotateX(20deg) rotateY(10deg) rotateZ(0deg)`.

How do I do this with regex in javascript? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the rotate properties will always be in order together, you can split the string with the following regular expression: `/\s(?=\S+\(.*?\))(?!rotate(?:Y|Z))/`.

The expression `/\s(?=\S+\(.*?\))(?!rotate(?:Y|Z))/` will match `\s` characters if they are followed by `(?=\S+\(.*?\))` some characters which contain parenthesis. It will also negate `\s` characters if they are followed by `rotateY`/`rotateZ` with `(?!rotate(?:Y|Z))`.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/s0jj0abz/)

```
var string = 'translate3d(20px, 5px, 10px) rotateX(20deg) rotateY(10deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew3d(20deg, 10deg) rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(100deg) rotateZ(-30deg)';
var properties = string.split(/\s(?=\S+\(.*?\))(?!rotate(?:Y|Z))/);
```

Returns:

```
[
    "translate3d(20px, 5px, 10px)",
    "rotateX(20deg) rotateY(10deg) rotateZ(0deg)",
    "skew3d(20deg, 10deg)",
    "rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(100deg) rotateZ(-30deg)"
]
```